# Video streaming server software

Tags: flash, stream, webcam, microphone

I need to stream webcam/microphone data from a browser to my server:

- Can I use anything else than Flash on the client side?
- What alternatives to Flash Media Server are there? Any open-source?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Red5, VLC, xuggler or gstreamer.

Answer (score 1):

There are a bunch of options for the server side: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_streaming_media_systems I'm using Wowza media server and Darwin Media Server